# SSH from server node to node with no SSH SERVER

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-kernel

In regards to Clustering between two nodes -

Can we SSH from node 1 that has SSH-SERVER Installed to node2 that has NO SSH SERVER Installed? I assume that node2 can't SSH to node1 as it has no SSH-server installed, but can node1 still able to ssh and log-in to node2?

Answer (score 1):

A server that has SSH-SERVER installed (it will be running a program called "sshd") can be contacted by other servers where the client program (ssh) is available.

The answer to your question is NO and NO.